# ps aux |grep 'asdf' grep: asdf: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, command-line, osx

For some reason a while back, the behavior of my command line changed, and I don't know why.  Using OSX, now Mountain Lion(although this behavior was present before the switch).

Using standard terminal, I would expect back some results from `ps`, but I get an error:

```
$ ps aux |grep 'asdf'
grep: asdf: No such file or director
```

This also shows up, for example, here:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
ln: /Users/peter/bin/subl: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Does it happens when you login as another user?
2. Check output of "set ; env; alias". Post it you can't find a problem.

Comment: bingo, that did it!  I had this line in my bash_profile: `alias grep='grep –colour=auto'`

Comment: Close. `grep --color=auto` is a good alias.. One I use in fact.

Answer (score 3):

You have something that's adding a bad option under the hood (or more precisely, something that isn't an option). It could be an alias for `grep` (or more rarely, a function or wrapper script), or the `GREP_OPTIONS` environment variable. Run the following commands:

```
type grep
echo "$GREP_OPTIONS"
```

If `grep` is a wrapper script, fix that. If `grep` is an alias or function, fix it; it's probably defined in `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/profile`. Same thing if `GREP_OPTIONS` is the culprit.